# .xaml page 'local' variable undeclared error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I would like to use Xamarin with XAML to design the data I want to use when designing, but I could not resolve the following error.
What do I need to do about the subject?

[image]

Comment: Well, the error is pretty obvious. You need to add a `xmlns:local` declaration to the `ContentPage` (right below `xmlns:x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a namespace for local. In the `ContentPage` head, add the following:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:name_of_your_project"
```

Then you can use the local namespace